# How to render <meta> tags first in Wicket?

Tags: java, wicket, meta, head

I have a Wicket application that contains a lot of Javascript in the headers. I would like to render my `<meta>` tags before any `<script>` tags (I'm trying to add these for getting indexed by search engines and it is *much* easier to read if they are on top of the source)

I thought this would help me (in my `BasePage`)

```
public void renderHead(final IHeaderResponse response) {
    response.render(MetaDataHeaderItem.forMetaTag(Model.of("description"), () -> "Cool generated description"));

    super.renderHead(response);
```

The `BasePage.html` relevant head section

```
...
<title wicket:id="pageTitle"></title>
<wicket:header-items />
...
```

The tags are render in the position of the `<wicket:header-items />`, but still I end up with all the child javascript headers above my `<meta>` tag.

What is the wicket-way of achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap it in a [`PriorityHeaderItem`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/8.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/head/PriorityHeaderItem.html):

```
    response.render(new PriorityHeaderItem(MetaDataHeaderItem.forMetaTag(Model.of("description"), () ->...)));
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried with tag `<wicket:header-items/>`? See [user guide](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/7.x/single.html#_header_contributors_positioning) for a full example.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to include this in my question.